# Translate vb.net to C#: one line of code

Tags: c#, vb.net

[This link](http://www.developer.com/net/vb/article.php/3769071/Inferring-an-XML-Schema-from-an-XML-Document.htm) offers sample code to infer the schema of an XML file, in VB.NET. One particular line fails in my translation to C#, namely,

```
Dim schema As XmlSchema = schemaSet.Schemas()(0)
```

My translation is

```
XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas()[0];
```

I cannot see what is wrong with my translation?

Comment: What's the compiler error that you get?  What type is `schemaSet`?

Comment: What is the type of `schemaSet`?

Comment: The type is System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaSet and the error is 'Cannot apply indexing with [] to an expression of type System.Collections.ICollection'

Comment: @Jacob @jzilla the link showns what it is it's a `XmlSchemaSet`. Why do I even bother if there is always someone like 5 seconds before me that says the exact same thing :P.....

Comment: Please post the entire code so that we can have a view where and what is going wrong.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[XmlSchemaSet.Schemas()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/142fs5cx.aspx) returns an `ICollection` which you can't access by index. If you use use .NET 3.5 you can use Linq to do:

```
schemaSet.Schemas().Cast<XmlSchema>().First();
```

Otherwise you have to use a `foreach` loop and stop after the first iteration.

Comment: +1 for being the first to point out that trying to use `[0]` won't work for an `ICollection`.

Comment: +1 for providing an answer that will actually solve the problem.

Comment: ChrisWue: Brilliant! It works. Thank you very much. I am curious - what will be the non Linq solution?

Comment: The non-Linq solution is: XmlSchema schema = schemaSet.Schemas().ElementAtOrDefault(0);  VB accepts indexing syntax in many cases where a proper index doesn't actually exist.

Comment: @DaveDoknjas: Hm, I don't quite see how this is non-Linq. As far as I can find [`ElementAtOrDefault`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb494386%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) is a Linq extension method operating on an `IEnumerable<T>`. Unless this is somehow different in VB.NET?

Comment: @ChrisWue: Yes - you're right - I stand corrected. It's not non-Linq, but it is the more direct conversion since VB allows an indexing shortcut on the ElementAtOrDefault extension method.